# PHP not posting information from database

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to post information from a database I created but it's not working.

I keep getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Content Calendar' ORDER BY Program' at line 1

I've googled and everything I show says that with a table with spaces (which I was stupid for naming it that btw) is using 'Content Calendar'. Is there another error that I'm not catching? Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
require_once("db_connx.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'Content Calendar' ORDER BY Program") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Program</th>
<th>Air Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Production</th>
<th>Promotion</th>
<th>Web</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Program'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Air Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Production'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Promotion'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Web'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
require_once("db_connx_close.php");
?>
```

Comment: Your table should not be wrapped in quotes but with backticks since you have two words seperated by a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions

1 is use backticks

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Content Calendar` ORDER BY Program") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

or 2 rename your table as `Content_Calendar`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Content_Calendar ORDER BY Program") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Oh and btw mysql_* is deprecated consider using mysqli or PDO =)

Answer (score 3):

Your table should not be wrapped in quotes but with backticks since you have two words seperated by a space.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Content Calendar` ORDER BY Program") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.