# Error adding info to database via php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add information to a database via PHP. However, when you submit the form it says "Error adding program." I've looked at the code and can't seem to find what's causing the error. Any advice?

Here's the form code:

```
<form name="Add" id="Add" method="post" action="programadd.php">
  <p>Program Name: 
    <input name="program" type="text" id="program" />
</p>
  <p>Air Date 
    <input name="air date" type="text" id="airdate" />
</p>
  <p>Description 
    <input name="description" type="text" id="description"  />
</p>
<p>Production
    <input name="production" type="text" id="production" />
</p>
<p>Promotions
    <input name="promotion" type="text" id="promotion"  />
</p>
<p>Community
    <input name="community" type="text" id="community" />
</p>
<p>Web
    <input name="web" type="text" id="web"  />
</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

And here's the code that adds the info into the db.

```
<?php require_once("db_connx.php");
$program = $_POST['Program'];
$airdate = $_POST['Air Date'];
$description =  $_POST['Description'];
$production = $_POST['Production'];
$promotion = $_POST['Promotions'];
$community = $_POST['Community'];
$web = $_POST['Web'];


if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 'Content Calendar' (Program, 'Air Date', Description, Production, Promotions, Community, 'Web') VALUES ('$program', '$airdate', '$description','$production', '$promotion', '$community', '$web')"))
{ echo "Program successfully added to the database <br />"; 
 }
else
{ echo "Error adding program"; }
require_once("db_connx_close.php");
?>
```

Comment: Never output a fixed useless error message when debugging. your `else` should be more like `die(mysql_error())`, which will tell you WHY the query failed.

Comment: Here's the usual warning about the mysql library: **This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

Comment: You have a space in `name="air date"` and `$_POST['Air Date']` **that is invalid**; use an underscore and make the other changes respectively. Plus, you have a space in your table and column names, use backticks or use an underscore, you've already been told about that in [**your other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22925105/); *I remember.* --- There are too many errors in your code for me to answer. If someone hits it right on the nailhead; great.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the OP already being told not to use spaces for tables and/or column names but use underscores to join both words.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use single quotes on column names , use backticks instead or let them be as it is.

#### The right way...

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `Content Calendar` (`Program`, `Air Date`, `Description`, `Production`, `Promotions`, `Community`, `Web`) VALUES ('$program', '$airdate', '$description','$production', '$promotion', '$community', '$web')")
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: you've introduced other errors now. `Air Date` **MUST** be quoted, because it has a space in the name, ditto for `Content Calendar`

Comment: Thanks Marc (modified it) , so will that be considered a reserved word ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: no, but special characters. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Comment: [`Too many errors in OP's code`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945938/error-adding-info-to-database-via-php#comment35031257_22945938) @ShankarDamodaran [`Voted to close`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945938/error-adding-info-to-database-via-php#comment35031397_22945938)

Comment: no, but remember that spaces are a separator in SQL. there'd be no way for the DB to know if `SELECT Air Date FROM ...` was a single field, v.s. the actual functional `SELECT Air AS Date FROM ...`. Since field aliases aren't allowed in insert queries, your unquoted version would be a syntax error, while the select version MIGHT work if there happens to be a real field named `Air`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB :) !! Thanks  VMai . No prob Fred ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issues

```
INSERT INTO 
'Content Calendar' <--
(
  Program, 
 'Air Date', <--
 Description, 
 Production, 
 Promotions, 
 Community, 
'Web' <--
```

They should all be enclosed with `` as

```
INSERT INTO 
    `Content Calendar`
    (
      Program, 
     `Air Date`, 
     Description, 
     Production, 
     Promotions, 
     Community, 
     Web
```

> **Thumb rules :**
>
> if you have a table name or colum name as "Some Name" meaning a space
>   in between then you must enclose them with back ticks ``
>
> If you are using any reserved keywords they also must be enclosed
>   within backticks
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 'Content Calendar' (Program, 'Air Date', Description, Production, Promotions, Community, 'Web') VALUES ('$program', '$airdate', '$description','$production', '$promotion', '$community', '$web')"))
{ echo "Program successfully added to the database <br />"; 
 }
else
{ echo "Error adding program"; }
```

To

```
if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `Content Calendar` (`Program`, `Air Date`, `Description`, `Production`, `Promotions`, `Community`, `Web`) VALUES ('$program', '$airdate', '$description','$production', '$promotion', '$community', '$web')"))
{ echo "Program successfully added to the database <br />"; 
 }
else
{ echo "Error adding program"; }
```